# Complex structure on the tangent space to normal bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, solution-verification, vector-bundles

Consider a compact submanifold $X\hookrightarrow Y$ and its normal bundle $N\to X$:
$$0\to TX\to TY|_X \to N \to 0$$

[There is](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1875492/is-a-tubular-neighborhood-always-diffeomorphic-to-the-whole-normal-bundle) a diffeomorphism which identifies $N$ with a tubular neighborhood $\tilde N\subset Y$ of $X$.

Now move to the tangent spaces. It can be shown that $T\tilde N\subset TY$ is a tubular neighborhood of $TX\hookrightarrow TY$. Hence we can identify the total space $TN$ (which is the tangent space of the normal bundle) with the normal bundle of $TX$ in $TY$:

$$0\to TTX \to TTY|_{TX} \to TN \to 0$$

> I would like to prove that $\pi^*N\oplus \pi^*N\simeq TN$, where $\pi\colon TX\to X$ is the projection. (And hence $TN$ can be given a structure of a complex vector bundle over $TX$).

This "simple verification is left to the reader" in M.F. Atiyah, I. Singer, *Index of Elliptic Operators: I*, page 497.

W can use the fact that $\pi$ is deformation retraction to get an exact sequence

$$0\to \pi^*TX \to \pi^* TY|_X \to \pi^*N \to 0$$

which we sum up with itself

$$0\to \pi^*TX \oplus \pi^*TX \to \pi^* TY|_X \oplus \pi^* TY|_X \to \pi^*N \oplus \pi^*N \to 0$$

Now using

$$TTX\simeq \pi^*TX \oplus \pi^*TX, \quad TTY|_{TX} \simeq \pi^* TY|_X \oplus \pi^* TY|_X$$

we get
$$\pi^*N \oplus \pi^*N\simeq TN.$$

I wonder if the above sketch is right or if you have seen a similar topic explained somewhere. (In two books on the index theorem I know this lemma is very briefly commented).

Comment: This notation is unbearable. We're using $T$ for the tangent bundle functor but then $TN$ for the tubular neighborhood, also called $N$? But then we identify with the normal bundle, which we also called $N$. Note that the tubular neighborhood is diffeomorphic to only a neighborhood of the zero section of $N$. Also, the correct exact sequence defining the normal bundle $N$ should be $$0\to TX \to TY|_X \to N\to 0.$$ Can you please sort this stuff out and edit?

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you for your comments, I hope this is clearer now. Unfortunately the construction here is quite complicated – $N$ is the normal bundle of $X$ in $Y$ _and_ $TN$ is the normal bundle of $TX$ in $TY$. (And this needs a stronger version of the tubular neighborhood theorem, as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1875492/is-a-tubular-neighborhood-always-diffeomorphic-to-the-whole-normal-bundle)).

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: @ShubhankarSahai Thank you!